# try with resource printwriter

Tags: filenotfoundexception, printwriter, try-with-resources

I am trying to learn how to use try with resources.  First I tried to put      java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File(filename) in the resource parenthesis, but netbeans told me that it is not autoclosable.  Am I properly handling this exception? I was under the impression that the Exception would be generated in the line where I define the file class object.

```
//This method writes to a csv or txt file, specify full filepath (including
//extension)  Each value will be on a new line
public void writeFile(String filename)
{
    java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File(filename);
    try(java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(myFile))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            //print all used elements line by line
            outfile.println(Integer.toString(this.getElement(i)));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
        //print error
    }

}//end writeFile(String)----------------------------------------------------
```